# Parametric equation of a circle in polar coordinates using Chebyshev distance

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces, polar-coordinates

Ok so let's say we have the following diagram in euclidean coordinates:

[image]

In that diagram we can see exactly 9 cells. If I wanted to visit ONLY the outer cells, I could start at one cell, turn around by some angle keeping the same distance (in polar coordinates) and repeat.

Now let's assume that we have a similar scenario in Chebyshev distance but that looks like a grid:

[image]

Just like in the prior diagram we could iterate through the outer circle by increasing an angle. We would like to also be able to walk the outer edges of the grid in a similar fashion.

For example like this:

[image]

The purpose of this question is that I am trying to understand how to map curves in polar coordinate sin euclidean spaces to Chebyshev coordinates.

This is the next level of the circular pattern btw:
[image]

Comment: You stressed about Chebyshev distance, so you actually want the each circular of $r < 1$ to be mapped to a square (with some side length less than unity) with orthogonal (sharp) edges? You don't want any smoothing?

Comment: No, no smoothing, I want to visit each cell in the periphery exactly once.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how are you going to construct the next-next order where there are $49$ sections? Going from $9$ to $25$ is coincidentally nice, as you have an additional $16$ that matches perfectly with the inner layer of $8$ (which was originally the outmost layer). Going from $25$ to $49$ sees an additional $24$ in the outmost layer, so how are they going to be aligned in relation to the $16$?

Comment: Also, do you want explicitly the mapping for each finite $n = (2m+1)^2$ pieces, or are you actually interested in the limiting case where $n \to \infty$?

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin The pattern in the circle matches the pattern in the square. I have to think about the next level a little bit more.